# ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to perform database related operations on my newly upgraded app(Rails 5) and I'm unable to perform destructive database commands locally.
`rails db:reset` or `rails db:drop` .

The trace results with the following data,

```
rails db:drop --trace
** Invoke db:drop (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Invoke db:check_protected_environments (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config
** Execute db:check_protected_environments

rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError: 

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run: 

    bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development
```

What I've tried so far are,

1. Setting `bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development`, doesn't change anything still the error occurs.
2. Setting Environment variable manually to development.

None of these helped. I'm Looking for a fix or workaround.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23279#issuecomment-267087520

Comment: Just in case this was your issue, We were running into this on Rails 5.0.x with MySQL 8.x. We had to upgrade Rails to 2.x in order for this to work.

Answer (score 32):

### Two Fixes to `ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError`

The other answers here describe the problem very well, but lack proper solutions. Hoping this answer helps someone experiencing this issue.

#### Why this error is happening

This incorrect error message is a result of [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22967) designed to prevent destructive actions on production databases. As [u/pixelearth correctly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309734/1038034), Rails 4.2 defines the 'key' field in the `ar_internal_metadata` table to be an integer, and Rails 5+ (including Rails 6) expects this to be a string with the value, `environment`. When Rails 5 and Rails 6 run this safety check, they incorrectly raise an `ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError` as the code is incompatible with the Rails 4 schema format.

#### Fix #1: Override the safety check in Rails 5+

**Please remember, the safety check was implemented as a result of [so many users dropping their production databases by accident](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/06/07/rails-5-prevents-destructive-action-on-production-db.html). As the question describes, the operations are destructive.

From the terminal:

```sh
rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=development DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
# and/or
rails db:drop RAILS_ENV=test DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
```

As noted [here](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/06/07/rails-5-prevents-destructive-action-on-production-db.html), the `DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1` flag disables the environment check. After, you can run a `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=development`, for example, to recreate your database with the correct schema in the `ar_internals_metadata` table.

#### Fix #2: Revert to Rails 4, drop database, go back to Rails 5+ and recreate

From the terminal:

```sh
git log
# grab the commit hash from before the upgrade to Rails 5+

git checkout **hash_from_rails_4**
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=development
rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=test

git checkout master

# now things should work
rails db:migrate
```

Again, please ensure you are not pointing at a production database when overriding this functionality. Alternatively, it would be possible to directly modify the schema of this table. If you're experiencing this error in production, you may need to take this approach.

Comment: For **Fix #2** you don't need to revert to Rails 4 to drop the database; instead just drop the database yourself and try again (this worked for me); i.e.: `psql`, then `\l` to find the name of my test database, then I dropped it with `drop database my_project_test;`, then exited. Then I was good to go  thanks for helping me find this solution!

Answer (score 14):

This happened because, for some reason, your table `ar_internal_metadata` got deleted or changed.
If you cannot drop the database via the command line, you need to do it via your DBMS or database client.
Then, just run `rails db:create db:migrate` to create and run the migrations.

Answer (score 5):

For posterity, my issue was that this schema was generated by a rails 4 app and the current app using it is rails 5. With rails 5 the structure of the ar_internal_metadata table has changed slightly. The key field needs to be a string and contain the word 'environment', not an integer. This error only goes away when this is changed.

It should look like this in Rails 5

[image]

ie, change the type of ar_internatl_metadata #key to string...

My situation is a bit uncommon involving a rails 4 app and a rails 5 app sharing the same db. When I need to "update", I have a task:

```
  puts "Modifying Rails 4 schema to fit Rails 5 schema"
  file_name = "./db/schema.rb"
  rails_4_ar_internal_metadata = 'create_table "ar_internal_metadata", primary_key: "key", force: :cascade do |t|'
  rails_5_ar_internal_metadata = 'create_table "ar_internal_metadata", primary_key: "key", id: :string, force: :cascade do |t|'
  new_schema = File.read(file_name).gsub(rails_4_ar_internal_metadata, rails_5_ar_internal_metadata)
  File.write(file_name, new_schema)
```

Comment: So what are the steps in code you used to rectify the problem?

Comment: so you used a GUI to modify this?  do you know how to  do it in pure code?

Answer (score 3):

Console rails

```
bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development
```

Answer (score 1):

I had

```
bundle exec rake db:drop
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoEnvironmentInSchemaError: 

Environment data not found in the schema. To resolve this issue, run: 

        rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development
```

And, indeed, **simply running `rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development` made the problem go away**.

#### Why did this happen?

It happened because I tried to drop the database and create it / migrate it, however, I had a syntax error in the migration (datatype and column name in the wrong places). Check your migration file for any silly errors

Specifically I had

```rb
t.submitted :boolean, default: false
```

instead of

```rb
t.boolean :submitted, default: false
```